# How to create Sink with some MaterializedValue

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I can construct simple sink like this:

```
Flow[Int].to(Sink.ignore)
```

However, this sink is of type `Sink[Int, NotUsed]`, while I need some materialized value type. How can I create e.g. `Sink[Int, String]`?

Answer (score 0):

`Flow[Int]` is short for `Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed]`. So its materialized value is `NotUsed`. Also `to(Sink.ignore)` is short for `toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.left)`. It basically keeps the materialized value of the first element of the two elements you are connecting together (in this case `Flow[Int]`). It depends on how you want to convert the flow of ints to Strings. For example, you could do something like:

```
val x: Sink[Int, Future[immutable.Seq[String]]] = Flow[Int].map(_.toString).toMat(Sink.seq)(Keep.right)
```

Comment: My problem is I have a source of type `Source[Message, Control]`. In normal flow, at the end I need this `Control`. However, in case of errors I want to divert the stream. To divert it I need a `Sink[Error, Control]`, because I need the Control at the end of the stream, but I can't create such a sink :(